# How to validate source data using a Range validation table in Excel Power query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, vba

Can anyone please help me on this?
I am trying to validate the source data in 3 columns BU - Act - Dept in the Range validation Data [BU - Beginning Act - End Account - Beginning Dept - End Dept] (screenshot attached).[image: Data]

BU is a single column in validation table but Act & Dept columns are range columns. I need to check if the BU - Act - Dept combo exists in Range data. 
So does Power query has any functionality to validate the source data using a nested join?
This needs to be done in Excel power query and not formulas because the validation Range file has more than 1 million records.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how efficient this is, but it works in principle.

---

I'll assume you have both tables loaded into the Query Editor with names `Source` and `Validation`.

First, choose the `Source` query and merge in the `Validation` table, matching on `Source[Unit] = Validation[BU]` for a left outer join.

Once merged, expand all the columns except `Validation[BU]`. This will give you a table with more rows since it will pull over every row in `Validation` that corresponds to the `Source[Unit]`.

[image: Expand Columns]

Now you can write a validation `Status` column. Add Column > Custom Column:

```
= if [Account] >= [Beg Act] and [Account] <= [End Act] and
     [Dept] >= [Beg Dept] and [Dept] <= [End Dept]
  then "Valid" else "Invalid"
```

Now that you have this column, group by the first three columns and take the max over the new custom column, `Status`. This should reduce your table back to its original size and give "Valid" in the `Status` column if that row matched any of the conditions that were pulled over from the `Validation` table, otherwise "Invalid".

[image: Group By]

Comment: Awesome! you are a genius. Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!

Comment: Hi Alexis, Do you have any idea about the Power Query question in following thread [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280170/how-to-load-file-to-excel-power-query-from-sftp-site [link]