# How to load file to Excel Power query from SFTP site

Tags: excel, powerbi, vba

Can anyone please help me on this?
I am trying to load a file to Excel Power Query from the SFTP site and I don't see any option. 
Following are the sample WINSCP SFTP site credentials:

```
File Protocol: SFTP
Host Name: ftp.test.com
Port Number: 22
Username: Test1
Password: XXXX
```

As shown in the below code snippet, I can load it from my local C drive, but Can you let me know how I can load it from SFTP drive site?

```
let
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\Documents\Winscp\acct_dept.dat"),[Delimiter="|", Columns=7, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image: WINSCP SFTP Drive]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I don't think there is a connector that will do this.

There is an [idea on the Power BI forums](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/11057568-sftp) that you can vote for related to this.

There might be possible workarounds if you're willing to do some scripting as suggested in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/63wz8a/how_to_load_source_text_data_files_from_an_sftp/), but I don't fully understand how that would work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexis. I voted for the idea. The reddit workaround doesn't tell us how we can integrate that with power query. It just shows the WINSCP automation

Comment: Hi Alexis, Do you have any idea about the Power Query question in following thread [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453462/excel-power-query-how-to-create-final-table-based-on-joins