# Excel Power Query - How to create final table based on Joins

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, vba

Can you please help me in creating a final table using Excel Power Query based on the logic mentioned in below screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by myself. Following are the steps:
1) I created a unique country code list with 1 column (Origin & Destination)
2) Left join with Origin table and then got the destination code from common table
3) added a custom column to get all rows except where origin = Destination.

In this way I got the Outbound column values.